# Dynamically Creating Pages On Button Click

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 to create an app. So far, I have a floating action button, when you click it you can add a new item to a list (starts empty) that is displayed on screen. Each item has name and a button.

I want it so that whenever a button is pressed on the item, it goes to a page for that specific item.

I do not have the faintest idea how to do this so, this leaves me with a few questions:

1) Should I have one page premade and dynamically change the contents of it based on item button clicked OR whenever item is created, dynamically create a page unique to that item?

2) Based on the last question, what is the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: In Angular you can use routing to display a different component whenever a button is pressed. This page has an example app that does almost exactly what you ask: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Basically create detail-page and upon that specific item click use router to navigate to the detail page from your master (list) page. in the (click) handler pass details of that item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your idea is what angular solves or why we call it SPA in the first place. 
you need first to check Routing in Angular and try to learn and apply to it and you will find what you are looking for - specifically in routing params -.

Check these links for more information: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba2QIjUwi9E 
https://angular.io/guide/router 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/11/a-complete-guide-to-routing-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; Answers**
Question 1: Dynamically change the contents of the page based on the item buttons
Question 2: I just answered it in question 1.

**Explanation**:
You need to first understand how a new page gets created at its simplest form; it adds more code to the application that defines the new page.

Now, try asking yourself, should you on-the-fly add more code to your already built/published application or should you just build one page that dynamically loads different information based on the data/parameters provided to that page? Which one seems more feasible and why?